# cancel current event click and ajax call when another button is pressed

Tags: jquery, ajax

My problem is that if I click a button and the ajax has not returned yet and I click another button (or the same button) then I end up getting two tables on screen instead of one.

Scenario : 
I am building a form and presenting a set of options based of drop down selections. Year/Make/Model combo's bring back a set of product lines - Carpets/Bumpers/Floor Mats/ Sound Deadners etc. Each one of those will become a button and when pressed will bring back the products for that product line.

The products are then looped over and I create a table via javascript to display them. If I push a button once and wait for the table to be displayed everything is good. If I choose another product line the products table is removed and then the ajax call returns the new products and build them into a table again via javascript. The problem I get is when the same button or a different product line button is clicked before a table is built from the first click I get two tables showing.

Comment: Any chance of including the code you have .... HTML / JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without really understanding your question due to is vague nature I can only really suggest looking at the following -> the [jQuery AJAX Global events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Specifically the `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxComplete()` methods you could use these to disable buttons with the same class on `ajaxStart` - then re-enable them on `ajaxComplete`

Example :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
  $('.buttonsclass').attr('disabled','disabled');; 
}).ajaxComplete(function(){ 
  $('.buttonsclass').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: This is the correct method. Or if you want to get fancy you can hide the botton and show a div with an ajax loading indicator.

Answer (score 1):

You can `abort` the previous ajax request using `abort()` method of xhr object. Try this

```
$(document).ready(
     var  xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            success: function(data) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    };

    //If you want to abort this call on some condition just do this
    xhr.abort();
);
```

Comment: That's like having a crosswalk button reset the timer to "light change" every time you press the button...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind a single click handler, then rebind it when your ajax is finished. A little less work than turning it off and on.

```
function clickhandler(){
  //your button actions
}

//the doc ready bind
$(yourButton).bind('click',clickhandler);

$.ajax({
    url:'your url',
    complete : function(){
        //rebind it when it's safe to do so again
        $(yourButton).bind('click',clickhandler);
    }
});
```